# readdir and scandir 

Tags: php

On my localhost machine, I have two files :

`IMG_9029_измен.размер.jpg` and `słońce32 opalenier1.jpg`

I want to get filename of themes by **scandir() or readdir()** but can't get extractly filename. They are like this:

```
IMG_9029_?????.??????.jpg  and slonce32 opalenier.jpg

Window XP SP3, php5.2.12
```

How I can get filename like `IMG_9029_измен.размер.jpg and słońce32 opalenier1.jpg` ?

Comment: Is your filename in unicode? and when you output the filenames to your webpage, is the webpage encoding in unicode too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977635/how-to-open-file-in-php-that-has-unicode-characters-in-its-name

Answer (score 8):

I assume that your php encoding is utf-8.

```
$files = scandir($dirname);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = iconv ( "windows-1251" , "UTF-8", $file );
    echo $filename ."\n";
}
```

It should work for first file, but I don't know which encoding use for second file.

The main problem is that php 5 don't support utf-8 for file operations. It is internally ansi. So it reads file names using ansi api (only 8bit encoding).

Answer (score 1):

The names are probably right, but you need to set the encoding of your page to UTF-8.

Add this to the header section of your pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Then convert your strings to UTF8 so the special characters show up correctly.

I made a function that does it, it's called `Encoding::toUTF8().`

Usage:

```
$utf8_string = Encoding::toUTF8($utf8_or_latin1_or_mixed_string);
```

Download:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/186012/PHP/forceUTF8.zip

Comment: thank for suggestion.filename was changed to IMG_9029_?????.??????.jpg
when i use readdir() or scandir(). how to encode with this name.I think it is not possible