# Cannot read local file with accented characters using PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, windows, encoding, file-get-contents, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to do something simple but it wont let me. I have this code:

```
$get = file_get_contents("resumé.html");
```

but I get this error msg:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(resumé.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\mysite\index.php on line 36
```

It appears I cant open/read files with foreign/accented characters and I dont know why. I tried using functions like `mb_convert_encoding()` and `urlencode()` but they dont work..

So how am I supposed to do this without resorting to renaming my file to resume.html?

Comment: Your filesystem is probably using a different encoding than whatever you're using to enter that filename. Try `var_dump(glob('res*'));` to see what the filename looks like from PHP's perspective. That said, you should try to avoid non-ascii characters in filenames for simplicity's sake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977635/how-to-open-file-in-php-that-has-unicode-characters-in-its-name
and see "wfio"

Comment: Thank you Shailesh Singh for the wfio extension its great and works!