# First letter from file name not good

Tags: php

I use UTF-8 letters. It's works fine, but if first letter from file is "č", "ž", "š"... not work good.
File name is: ča ča ča.doc
I have this code:

```
$name1 = $_FILES["file"]["name"];  //here is ča ča ča.doc
$ext = pathinfo($name1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //here is doc
$name = basename($name1, $ext); //here is "a ča ča." missing first letter
```

This not work only if here is first leter "č,š,ž,đ..."

Answer (score 1):

**PHP** [**iconv()**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)

Try to encode the `$name1` yet again to a different encoding, **Windows-1252**.

```
//encode to windows-1252 to save to the filesystem
$name1 = $_FILES["file"]["name"];  //here is ča ča ča.doc
$encoded_filename = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$name1);
```

or **CP858**

```
$name1 = $_FILES["file"]["name"];  //here is ča ča ča.doc
$encoded_filename = iconv("UTF-8", "CP858//IGNORE", $name1)
```

After 30 min r&d on this, i found, you could try this:

```
$search = array('š','á','ž','í','ě','é','ř','ň','ý','č',' ');
$replace = array('s','a','z','i','e','e','r','n','y','c','-');

$code_encoding = "UTF-8"; // this is my guess, but put whatever is yours
$os_encoding = "CP-1250"; // this is my guess, but put whatever is yours

$name1 = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$name1 = iconv($os_encoding , $code_encoding, $name1); // convert before replace
$name1 = str_replace($search, $replace, $name1);
```

> Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767011/2236219

Comment: I got empty string on the end

Comment: `$name = str_replace($ext, '', $name1);` Here is how I repair this. And now work.