# Working with Japanese filenames in PHP 5.3 and Windows Vista?

Tags: php, windows, unicode, utf-8

I'm currently trying to write a simple script that looks in a folder, and returns a list of all the file names in an RSS feed. However I've hit a major wall... Whenever I try to read filenames with Japanese characters in them, it shows them as ?'s. I've tried the solutions mentioned here: [php readdir problem with japanese language file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482342/php-readdir-problem-with-japanese-language-file-name) - however they do not work for some reason, even with:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

At the top (Exporting as plain text until I can sort this out).

What can I do? I need this to work and I don't have much time.

Comment: did you try to see what page properties do you get? With Firefox (Right click - page info) and you need to have Encoding: UTF-8, else something's wrong in your headers.

Comment: I don't think there's a solution for this. PHP does not use the unicode versions of windows apis internally and the multibyte versions do not accept UTF-8 as a codepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in PHP. Write a small C program to read directories and call that program from PHP.

See also:
http://en.literateprograms.org/Directory_listing_(C,_Windows)
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread74944.html
http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/reading-a-directory-in-windows-36169.html

Comment: You call this doing it in PHP? :p It's an acceptable work-around, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
function fx_dir_utf8 ($path)
{
    // use this as failback on windows for usual dir listing
    // give it a UTF-8 path and receive a UTF-8 listing
    $path       = iconv ('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $path);
    $cmd        = 'cmd /U /C dir '. str_replace ('/', '\\', $path);
    // windows command line returns CP850 or UTF-16LE
    $dir_str    = shell_exec ($cmd);
    $dir_str    = iconv ('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $dir_str);
print_r ($dir_str);

    // further parse $dir_str
    return ($dir_str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. It is a limitation of PHP itself. PHP does not use the wide WIN32 API calls, so you're limited by the codepage. UTF-8 (65001) is not valid for this purpose.

If you set a breakpoint at `readdir_r()` in `win32\readdir.c`, you'll see that `FindNextFile` already returns a filename with question marks in place of the characters you want, so there's nothing you can do about it, apart from patching PHP itself.

Comment: Well, that sucks... Since PHP is not an option, what would an alternative language be that handles Window's filename encoding? I just need to export an RSS feed of filenames in a folder (Along with the exact path and some other simple text).

Comment: I suggest you use Java. ROME (https://rome.dev.java.net/) is a very good RSS library.

Answer (score 1):

This displays Japanese filenames correctly on a Windows server

```
if ($handle = opendir($this->dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        $name = mb_convert_encoding($file, "UTF-8", "SJIS-win" );
        echo "$name<br>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, no, as others stated it, PHP **CAN'T** do it… *Shame on you PHP!*

As others also suggested, one alternative could be to write a proxy in another language that can read those file names:

Some suggested C, but personally I found **Python** much more simpler/attractive (here Python3).

** **BE SURE TO SANITIZE YOUR VARIABLES BEFORE USING THIS** **

```
$success = (bool)(int)shell_exec('python -c "import os;'.
    'os.chdir(\''.$dir.'\'); '.
    'import urllib.parse; '.
    'file_list = tuple(map(urllib.parse.quote_plus, os.listdir())); '.
    'print(int(\''.urlencode($_GET['src']).'\' in file_list and \''.urlencode($_GET['src'].'.part').'\' not in file_list))"'
);
```

Yup, not pretty, but this snippet allowed me to check against file names by `urlencode`'ing them.

(**Ndla:** That particular snippet was used to find out when a file was done downloading with Firefox without having to mess with the API. Not the best but WORKING and fast to setup)