# PHP: How to list the files with non-english file names, using DirectoryIterator?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

The files inside a folder will be with the utf-8 names like:

- 日本.txt

While i use this code to list the files inside the dir:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "<br>";
}
```

And i also have correct html header like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

But anyway, the final output is being like following:

- ??.txt

How can i make it work?

Comment: Have you emitted a `Content-Type` header indicating that you'll be serving content with the same character set encoding as the character set encoding of the file names?

Comment: @Charles yes, please read again the question. I've added it.

Comment: Replace the `echo $filename` with `echo urlencode($filename)` -- does the output match the expected UTF-8 codepoints?  For example, "日" seems to be [U+65E5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/65e5/index.htm), which should URL-encode as `%E6%97%A5`

Comment: When i use `echo urlencode($filename)`, the output is then, `%3F%3F.txt`.

Comment: `%3F` is a question mark.  That's pretty darn astounding.  What happens if you use [`opendir()`](http://php.net/opendir) and [`readdir()`](http://php.net/readdir) instead of a `DirectoryIterator`?  Also, is the server on *nix or Windows?

Comment: Same output with `opendir()` and `readdir()`. I'm testing with XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: Okay.  [This blog post](http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php) suggests that PHP + Unicode filenames + Windows = incorrect behavior.  The comments are a trainwreck, but they provide some insight into what PHP is doing wrong.  I'm not (yet) going to post this as an answer, as I should have been in bed two hours ago and I'm sure that some wizard will drop in overnight with more knowledge for you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2947941/469210 for detailed answer for this issue on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, this is ultimately a dupe of that question.  Blah.