# PHP file upload wrong file name encoding

Tags: php, html, file-upload, utf-8

Im doing a webpage and have a problem with file upload, that changes the file name umlauts into a weird name.

For example when i upload a file called "töö.docx" and look at the name in the uploaded folder, it shows me this "tĆ¶Ć¶.docx".

When i call out the name of the file in index.php it shows me the correct name "töö.docx".

But after i go into the upload folder and change the name "tĆ¶Ć¶.docx" manually into "töö.docx" and than call out the name of the file in index.php, it shows me "t��.docx" which is wrong.

Here is the code for upload in index.php:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <strong>File upload:</strong>
  <small>(max 8 Mb)</small>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the upload controller code:

```
$doc_list = array();
   foreach (new DirectoryIterator('uploads/') as $file)
{
   if ($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue;
   $doc_list[] = $file->getFilename();
}

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename( isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] : "");
$file = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) ? $_FILES["fileToUpload"] : "";
$up_this = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) ? $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] : "";
$file_name = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] : "";

if (!empty($file)) {
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if (file_exists($file_name)) {
            echo "File already exists.";
            exit;
        } else {
            $upload =  move_uploaded_file($up_this, $target_file);
            if ($upload) {
                echo "File ". '"' . basename($file_name). '"' . " has been uploaded";
            } else if (!$upload) {
                echo "Could not upload file";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the variable $doc_list to call out the names of the documents in folder in index.php:

```
<div>
    <?php if (!empty($doc_list)) foreach ($doc_list as $doc_name) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $doc_name ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I've set the website charset into utf-8. and i still don't know why it's not displaying the correct file name with umlauts.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the filename in `utf8_encode(..)`

Comment: That fixed the file name on form but not the filename in the folder

Comment: When you say *"look at the name in the uploaded folder"*, how are you doing that? Also, how is `$doc_list` populated?

Comment: "look at the name in the uploaded folder" - by that i mean when i go into that folder and the umlauts of the file name have been replaced by thoseweird characters. $doc_list is an array from the controller that holds all the file names in uploads folder.

Comment: Program: PhpStorm; $doc_list is array that gets its items from foreach construct and uses the getFilename function

Comment: Sorry if my english is not so good. I use windows 8.1, PHPStorm encoding is set to utf-8, $doc_list source and everything else i use is already in the first post but if you missed it, this is all i use: $doc_list = array();
   foreach (new DirectoryIterator('uploads/') as $file)
{
   if ($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue;
   $doc_list[] = $file->getFilename();
}

Comment: My apologies, I did miss `$doc_list` at the top of your script. I assume you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your page's `<head>` section?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to iterate over non-English file names in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947941/how-to-iterate-over-non-english-file-names-in-php)

Comment: every page i have has a charset="utf-8" in it. I think something else is messing with the encoding either during move_uploaded_file or somewhere else.

Comment: i think its easier just to use preg_replace to remove the umlauts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `accept-charset="UTF-8"` like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" instead "UTF-8":

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```