# move_uploaded_file dose not support UTF 8 filename

Tags: php, file, upload

i can not save file whith utf-8 name

for example file saves by following name

```
ط·آ´ط·آ±ط¹آ©ط·ع¾ ط¸آ¾ط·آ§ط·آ±ط·آ³ ط¹آ¯ط¸ث†ط¹آ¯ط·آ±ط·آ¯ ط¸â€¦ط·آ§ط؛إ’ط·آ¹_ط·ع¾ط·آ³ط·ع¾_ddd 001
```

this is my code

```
move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"],ROOT_DIR."/uploads/gallery/".$filename);
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot save it? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: move_uploaded_file() doesn't care.... it's more likely to be an issue with the charset of your filesystem.... is your filesystem set to utf-8?

Comment: file saves with bad character.... how can i set filesystem to utf8

Comment: move_uploaded_file saves the file onto the system , it's the system which does not display correctly.Which Operating system are you using ?

Comment: im using xampp on windows

Comment: PHP doesn't support Unicode file names on Windows. Seriously.

Comment: you could keep the file names in a db table and map them with the record id

Comment: Related (and possibly a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2950046/13508