# SCAN Arabic FOLDERS php

Tags: php, utf-8, windows-7, arabic, scandir

When I scan folders and files with Arabic names, I can't print their actual names instead of the generated symbols.

OS: WINDOWS 7

```
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
foreach($files2 as $f)
   echo $f;
```

Comment: what is the OS that it's running under?

Comment: OS: WINDOWS 7 . .

Comment: see this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947941/1415724 - it may hold answers.

Comment: Via CLI or a web browser? Often terminals aren't able to display non-Ascii characters.