# filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for filenames with umlauts

Tags: php, utf-8, statistics, diacritics, filemtime

I use the PHP function **[filemtime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php)** to get the last modification time with PHP 5.3. This functions works very well but it seems to have some problems when the filenames have special characters (for example umlauts).

If I run it on a filename with umlauts

```
$stat = filemtime('C:/pictures/München.JPG');
```

then I get the output:

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for C:/pictures/München.JPG
```

If I rename the file from "München.JPG" to "Muenchen.JPG" and do the same thing again:

```
 $stat = filemtime('C:/pictures/Muenchen.JPG');
```

everything works fine!

My PHP file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM and I also tried:

```
clearstatcache();
$stat = filemtime(utf8_encode('C:/pictures/München.JPG'));
```

but it has not helped.

Comment: Do you have the same charset in the file as in your operating system?

Comment: Given it's a windows system, it's almost certainly NTFS, which is utf-16.

Comment: At the moment I use this script on a Windows 7 machine (with an NTFS formatted hard disk) but later I want to use it on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: Try a `scandir()` and report the raw (`bin2hex`) character string of the picture. Could be that you're out of luck though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482342/php-readdir-problem-with-japanese-language-file-name

Comment: Can you influence the way the files are named? URLEncoding the file names before storing would be an easy way out, for example - you would be guaranteed to have a file name that works on every system, and a `urldecode()` call can give you back the full string, no problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies! The scandir() function shows "M�nchen.JPG" which is "4df66e6368656e2e4a5047" with bin2hex. Unfortunately I can not simply rename the files so they must keep their names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the following code snippet I found out that the file encoding on Windows 7 is "ISO-8859-1":

```
$scandir = scandir('.')
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($scandir[0], 'ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, ASCII');
echo $encoding;
```

I've read that [utf8_decode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) converts a UTF-8 string to ISO-8859-1 so I ended up with this small code that works for my project:

```
$file = 'C:/pictures/München.JPG';
$lastModified = @filemtime($file);
if($lastModified == NULL)
    $lastModified = filemtime(utf8_decode($file));
echo $lastModified;
```

Thank you to all who have submitted a comment. You have steered me in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$dir    = 'uploads/';

        if (is_dir($dir)) { if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {                
                clearstatcache();
                if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) {                    
                    echo $file;
                    echo " - ";                    
                    echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d, Y H:i:s.", filemtime(utf8_decode($dir."/".$file)));
                    echo "<br>";
                }                
            }            

            echo "<br>";
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```