# PHP - Upload utf-8 filename

Tags: php, file-upload, character-encoding, upload

I'm Vietnamese and i want to upload a utf-8 filename like

`Tên Tệp Tiếng Việt.JPG`

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>utf-8</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
       if($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0 ) echo "FILE ERROR!"; 
       else 
         { 
           $base_dir = "D:/"; 
           $fn = $_FILES["upload"]["name"]; 

           $fn2 = $base_dir.$fn;

           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],$fn2); 
         } 
     } 
?> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

but when i upload that i see on my computer D:\ has a file like

`TÃªn Tá»‡p Tiáº¿ng Viá»‡t.JPG`

How to fix that thanks

Comment: On Windows you may have to use iconv() to convert it into ucs2

Comment: @Jack I try ` $fn2 = iconv("UTF-8","ucs2", $base_dir.$fn) ;` but get error iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `ucs2' is not allowed ?

Comment: It's `UCS-2` actually :)

Comment: i edit that to $fn2 = iconv("UTF-8","UCS-2", $base_dir.$fn); but i get new error  `move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty ..` and  `move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'E:\PHP\Xampp\tmp\php6B2C.tmp' ...` ? what is wrong

Comment: Which operating system you are using. With your code check out you system settings also because at the code part it look fine but at the os i am not sure you enable all the things

Comment: @simmant I using window8, english US keyboard ?

Comment: First things first. Can you *`echo`* the filename you receive on the server? Test whether the filename is *uploaded* encoded in UTF-8? Because *that* part is likely working. The problem is how PHP interacts with the file system when writing files, which basically depends on whatever the underlying filesystem does, which may be pretty ugly and complex in case of Windows. If the filename is *uploaded* fine in UTF-8 the question becomes *"how to write a filename in UTF-8"*, the answer to which may not be pretty.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm on Windows 8 chinese version, and I deal with similar problem with this:

```
$filename = iconv("utf-8", "cp936", $filename);
```

`cp` stands for `Code page` and `cp936` stands for [Code page 936](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Page_936), which is the default code page of simplified chinese version of Windows.

<strike>So  I think maybe your problem could be solved in a similar way:</strike>

```
$fn2 = iconv("UTF-8","cp1258", $base_dir.$fn);
```

I'm not quite sure whether the default code page of your OS is `1258` or not, you should check it yourself by opening command prompt and type in command `chcp`. Then change `1258` to whatever the command give you.

**UPDATE**

It seems that PHP filesystem functions can only handle characters that are in system codepage, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/599560/890138). So you have 2 choices here:

1. Limit the characters in the filename to system codepage - in your case, it's `437`. But I'm pretty sure that code page 437 does not include all the vietnamese characters.
2. Change your system codepage to the vietnamese one: `1258` and convert the filename to `cp1258`. Then the filesystem functions should work.

Both choices are deficient:

Choice 1: You can't use vietnamese characters anymore, which is not what you want.

Choice 2: You have to change system code page, and filename characters are limited to code page 1258.

**UPDATE**

How to change system code page:

Go to `Control Panel` > `Region` > `Administrative` > `Change system locale` and select `Vietnamese(Vietnam)` in the drop down menu.

Comment: +1 because I think this answer is going in the right direction. Since you'll need to choose the right codepage for the set of characters you want to use, this is of course hard to generalize.

Comment: i try and give: `Active code page: 437`, and i change to `$fn2 = iconv("UTF-8","cp437", $base_dir.$fn);` and give error like `Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in ` and some warning like `Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty` ...?

Comment: @trungkien Now I have no idea either. Try `cp1258`, maybe?

Comment: that's running look better than before :( but still not utf-8

Comment: i follow http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8 to change codepage to `1258`. The first I just change in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP`. But the second, i can't find `Autorun` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` ?

Comment: I just create Autorun string in `Command Processor` and put `@chcp 1258>nul` value. after i restart my computer and type `chcp` on `cmd` and get `Active code page: 1258` But when i run upload again then it's still not vietnamese file name :(

Comment: @trungkien That method won't work because it only changes the code page of the command prompt. See my update.

Answer (score 5):

This `meta` has no effect:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

because the web server has already sent `Content-Type` header, and thus decided what the encoding will be. Web browsers send forms in the same encoding. The `meta` is useful when user is off-line.

So you have to sned http header `Content-Type` by yourself:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

ensure that you put this before any html, content or whatever is sent.

---

Alternatively, `accept-charset` tag on `form` should work as weel:

```
 <form accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: i added <?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?> at first of file (file is my code in my question) but nothing work :(

Comment: @trungkien What browser are you using ? Try to watch network traffic and especially when you send form, check the sent (from browser) `content-type` header. Is there a `charset` ? You can also try adding `accept-charset="utf-8"` to `<form>`

Comment: I'm using firefox. How to watch network traffic?. I using firebug and i go to: `Net>All>Headers>Response Headers` and i see `Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8` on `Response Headers`. I try to add `accept-charset="utf-8"` but not working. Here is my `upload.php` file http://jsfiddle.net/nnBwV/

Comment: @trungkien Okay, I meant `content-type` in `Request Hedears`, take a look there.

Comment: in option `Request Headers From Upload Stream` has `Content-Type multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------18199138701329` ??

Comment: @trungkien that's it. There is no `charset`, which means that it is the same as the page is. My main suspect now is that your file is not saved as utf-8 - check that, also check php ini directive called `default_charset`. Ok, navigate to `Post` tab and find `source` category and line which looks like this: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="your_file.txt"` Is the filename of correct encoding ?

Comment: in php.ini has: `;default_charset = "UTF-8"`. i don't understand your mean `navigate to Post tab and find ..` what is `Post` tab?

Comment: @trungkien delete the `;` in the php.ini. I meant Post tab in firebug

Comment: i have been remove `;` but it still not working. I don't find any tab has name `Post` :(

Comment: accept-charset is important, apparently if not set it defaults to the document's charset, which may not be the correct one.  Spent an hour getting utf-8 to work correctly on multipart fileupload, every time.

Answer (score 3):

I am Persian and I have same problem with utf-8 character in my language.
I could solve my problem with this code:

```
$fn = $_FILES["upload"]["name"]; // name of file have some utf-8 characters
$name=iconv('utf-8','windows-1256', str_replace('ی', 'ي', $fn));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],$name );
```

**I am not sure** about vientam language but maybe you can use the same code as above with a few changes:

```
$fn = $_FILES["upload"]["name"]; // name of file have some utf-8 characters
$name=iconv('utf-8','cp936', $fn);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],$name );
```

Answer (score 1):

**The only solution**  I have found so far.. (2014 year):

1) I dont store files on my FTP in **UTF-8 string**. Instead, i use this function, to rename the uploaded files:

```
<?php
// use your custom function.. for example, utf8_encode
$newname  = utf8_encode($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $newname);
?>
```

2) Now  you can rename (or etc) **`$newname`**;

Comment: It Didn't Work On Windows

Answer (score 0):

For a start get detecting filename encoding (before uploading).

```
print_r($_FILES["upload"]);
```

Insert filename to [decoder](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/) and check encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! your question is about file name.

You must save your file name with iconv but read without this.

for saving:

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$unicode = iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', $name);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'photos/' . $name);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `photos` (`filename`) VALUES ('{$unicode}')");
?>
```

for reading:

```
<?php
$images = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `photos`');
if($images && mysql_num_rows($images) > 0) {
    while($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) {
        $name = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $image['filename']);
        echo '<img src="photos/' . $name . '"/>';
    }
    mysql_free_result($images);
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function convToUtf8($str) 
{ 
if( mb_detect_encoding($str,"UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, GBK")!="UTF-8" ) 
{ 

return  iconv("gbk","utf-8",$str); 

} 
else 
{ 
return $str; 
} 

}


$filename= convToUtf8($filename) ;
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$imgname     = $_FILES['img'] ['name'] ;
$imgsize     = $_FILES['img'] ['size'] ;
$imgtmpname  = $_FILES['img'] ['tmp_name'] ;
$imgtype     = $_FILES['img'] ['type'] ;
$size     = 1024;
$imgtypes    = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
$folder = "up";

if(empty($imgname)){
  echo "Shose ur photo";
}else if(!in_array($imgtype,$imgtypes)){
  echo "this photo type is not avalable";
}else if($imgsize > $size){
  echo "this photo is dig than 6 MB";
}else if($imgwidth > 5000){
echo "the file is to big";
}
else{
 move_uploaded_file($imgtmpname, $folder, $filename); 
}
```

Comment: sorry but, my question is about store utf-8 name of file on my computer?

Answer (score -3):

You can use this

```
$fn2 = basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);
```

Comment: It won't solve ant problem, be careful about what you are saying!