# how can i change the "character type" of a database in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, character

I'm using postgreSQL 9.1

I've set the Collation and the Character Type of the database to Greek_Greece.1253 and I want to change it to utf8

To change the collation I should use [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altercollation.html), right?

But how can I change the character type?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I ment to wright C instead of utf8. I would like to change the Collation and the Character Type to C

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i change database encoding for a PostgreSQL database using sql or phpPgAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380924/how-can-i-change-database-encoding-for-a-postgresql-database-using-sql-or-phppga)

Comment: @DietrichEpp The question you suggest, is about encoding. I'm asking about collation and character type

Comment: Then you are confused.  UTF-8 is not a character type, it is not a collation, UTF-8 is an encoding.  Windows 1253 is also an encoding, it is not a character type.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, I'm so sorry. I ment to wright C instead of utf8. Thanks for pointing out. I will edit the question

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "character type"?  In PostgreSQL, "character type" means `varchar(n)`, `text`, etc.  1253 is not a character type, and neither is C.

Comment: @DietrichEpp He is asking about Collation order (`LC_COLLATE`) and Character classification (`LC_CTYPE`).

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, what Igor, said. In the pgAdmin, I right click on the name of the database I click "Properties" and then on "Definition" I get the Collation and the Character Type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change default collation of an existing database. You need to `CREATE DATABASE` with the collation you need and then dump/restore your schema and data into it.

If you do not want to recreate the database - you can specify collation for every text collumn in your db.

Here is detailed postgres manual on collations: [`Collation Support`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html).

First line of this manual page states:

> LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE settings of a database cannot be changed after
>   its creation.

[`CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html), [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html), [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: I used pgAdmin to set the collation fo the table's column to `pg_catalog."C";`. The names store in the database fine. When I save Greek characters, I see Greek in the database. This whole question started because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946772/set-charset-when-saving-files-with-php). I still see the wrong characters uploaded in the folder. Is it because of the database?

Comment: @slevin The problem you pointed to is not about LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE. It is about character encodings (like `utf8`, `Windows 1253` and so on). If you want to work with unicode charactesr - to need to set database encoding to unicode (utf8) and make you application send strings in unicode.

Comment: @ The encoding of the database is utf8. The collation and the character set are different (Greek...). I will doublecheck everything...Anyhow, thanks for your time

Comment: @slevin If your DB already uses `utf8` as encoding - then probably your application sends the text with wrong encoding.

Comment: Igor, Thanks for your time. I specified collation for every text column in the database. As for the other problem, I also found a solution. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946772/set-charset-when-saving-files-with-php) if you like. Thanks