# move_uploaded_file with asian characters uploads to folder with wrong name

Tags: php, flash

I'm trying to make a website where you can upload flash .swf files. It works great and all except whenever a user uploads a flash file name with japanese or any other asian characters (tested with Japanese characters) it gives me the name wrong.

So this is the file: 
[image]

Before it starts moving the file im putting the information in the database.
Database:

> flash_id | flash_name | not relevant | flash_size | flash_date

[image]

After putting the flashes information in the database I move the file from the tmp folder to another folder where I store the uploads.
[image]

If you compare the file names from the first 2 pictures with the third one you can see it isn't the same.

Here is the code:

The variables map, filename and ext below are the values that were used in the moving process.

```
$map = 62;
$filename = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];
$ext = swf;

$str = "../uploads/$map/$filename.$ext";

if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        //sprintf('../uploads/%s/%s.%s',$map,$filename,$ext)
        $str
    )) {
        // Failed to move uploaded file.
        throw new RuntimeException(4);
    } else {
        try {
            $insq = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO flashes (flash_name, flash_size) VALUES (?,?)');
            $insq->bindParam(1, $filename);
            $insq->bindParam(2, $filesize);
            $insq->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(999);
        }
    }
    // File is uploaded successfully.
    echo 10;
```

Comment: sprintf isn't multi-byte string capable. and for such an absurdly simple string building exercise, you'd be better off just having `$str = "../uploads/$map/$filename.$ext"` anyways. printf/sprintf are really only useful for formatting numbers, e.g. `%3.7f` type things.

Comment: @MarcB I see. I've changed the sprintf with just a normal string. However this has not help fix the problem.

Comment: Plus, you're dealing with a database. are you sure that the db connection and db tables are set to the proper character set as well?

Comment: @MarcB Yes they are all in UTF-8. However I am only putting the flash info in the database. The variables $filename and $ext I get are not from the database but from the flash itself. So the $filename and $ext are the same ones used to put the information in the database.

Comment: are you sure that your conection is utf8? see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/453348)

Comment: @tttony Yes I am sure. Also the filename is not put from the database. But from the uploaded flash itself.

Comment: so the filename is correctly saved in the database, the problem is when you show the filename?

Comment: @tttony The problem is that when I move the file to another folder the files name is not correct anymore just like in the post pictures. The database shows that the name is correct up until the moment its used to rename the tmp_name with name.

Comment: ok the problem is that the file name is changed in the filesystem, take a look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18481737/453348), but I suggest that save the japanese file name in the db and create an unique name for the file but with ascii characters, and save it that in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution for this. So instead of trying to fix this I followed tttony's comment and made it so that the file_names are randomized and the file_name before randomizing is put in the database. So we can show it on our website with its original name however when we are going to download it we will receive a randomized file_name. However if you use the html `download="original_file_name"` attribute you can still make the user download it with the original file_name.