# file_get_contents can't find my file

Tags: php, file, unicode, character-encoding

I have a file `c:/localweb/img/안녕.png`

when I use,

```
$data = file_get_contents('c:/localweb/img/안녕.png');
```

I have a not found exception. I guess this is because there are korean chars.
The files' names need to use korean characters though.

Is there a way to get the file's data ? converting the string or something ?

Comment: Why does the filename *have* to have korean chars ?

Comment: @adeneo this is a SEO matter.

Comment: There is also an answer relative to your system codepage : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18481737/4726998

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP manual page they noted:

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you
>   need to encode the URI with urlencode().

Maybe this will help you, so it's going to be:

```
$data = file_get_contents(urlencode('c:/localweb/img/안녕.png'));
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: What has the manual quote to do with OP's problem? I don't see any spaces in OP's path?!

Comment: Because of: URI with special characters

Comment: I saw many answers but I think urlencode() is the right choice for a direct measure-taking. However I think your example lack of logic, urlencode will encode all the characters of your string. urlencode(<path to file>) is no likely to work as the returned string is just intended to be used in a url printable environment. I am gonna use the function to generate a filename both usable in php and html environment. +1 because your answer headed me on a way but I don't yet accept it as it is semantically poor.

Comment: OK np, i was just hoping that my answer was pushing you in the right way.  Did you figured it out? And would you share it here?

Comment: @D3F I can't, my question was selfishly refered as a duplicate.