# UTF8 encoding for a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using wordpress and added a function to change the uploads directory folder structure

everything goes as expected but when the function deals with Greek characters outputs text like

> ΓΒ‘ΓΒ…ΓΒΈΓΒ±ΓΒ―ΓΒΓΒµΓΒ„ΓΒΏ

to be more specific

i have setup the variables

`$client` that holds a client's name  and

`$customdir` that holds the directory path

```
$client='πελάτης';
$customdir ='/pm/' . $_POST['post_type'] . '/' . $_POST['YEAR']. '/' . $client;
```

I use the `$customdir` variable that contains `$client` var too, to create the uploads directory and if $client var is in english everything works flawlessly..

Can you help me to encode correctly the `$customdir` variable to be able to create greek named directories ??

Comment: What is the encoding of your script file?  Does your file system support UTF-8 file names?  See also the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for how to include useful diagnostics.

Comment: My script file is in utf-8, how can i check my filesystem support?

Comment: On modern systems, it should be fairly transparent out of the box.  For U*X including OSX, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-charset-encoding-is-used-for-filenames-and-paths-on-linux and if you are on Windows, see maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx for a start (but given your "huh?" response I assume you are not on Windows).

Comment: For context see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help i solved it by adding `setlocale (LC_ALL, "el_GR.UTF-8");`in the very first start of my function ...