# Encoding names of uploaded files

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I have a shell account and I created there a file uploader. It has two files. **upload.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Send</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
        <input name="thefile" type="file" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and **upload.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$thefile_tmp = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];
$thefile_name = $_FILES['thefile']['name'];

if(is_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp)) {
    move_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp, "files/$thefile_name");
}
?>
```

Everything works fine, but I want to be able to play with uploader on my computer (windows 7). So I installed Apache24 and php7 as is this [tutorial](https://danielarancibia.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/installing-apache-2-4-and-php-7-for-development-on-windows/). I noticed however, that when I upload file with polish characters (and i need them) it changes them to some strange symbols. I found a solutin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename). Namely I changed **upload.php** to

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$thefile_tmp = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];
$thefilename = $_FILES['thefile']['name'];
$thefile_name = iconv("utf-8", "ISO-8859-2", $thefilename);

if(is_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp)) {
    move_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp, "files/$thefile_name");
}
?>
```

Everything works fine on my compluter. However when I put such **upload.php** on my shell account, it changes polish characters to strange symbols.

I deduced that this mismatch is due to servers' php configurations.

> So I want to change configuration on my computer, so that first version of **upload.php** would work.

I looked into **phpinfo()** in my shell account and I tried to set similar setting on my computer **phpinfo()**.

I tried to change **default_charset** in **core** but it didn't help.

I also tried to change **iconv.input_encoding,iconv.internal_encoding,** and **iconv.output_encoding**. None of this helped neither.

There are so many options that I am lost.

---

**Version info**

My shell account:

- **PHP Version** 5.4.45-0+deb7u2
- **SERVER_SOFTWARE** Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

My computer:

- **PHP Version** 7.0.5RC1
- **SERVER_SOFTWARE**  Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/7.0.5RC1

Comment: The problem is on the Windows end. It's not recommended to do PHP development on one operating system when you are deploying to a different operating system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton So it would be recommended to install Debian and later Apache as well as PHP on that beast. Before I do so I would like to ask, if there are any things I should be careful about?