# File Upload Failed in mac when special chars are present

Tags: file-upload

We receive file content as empty in the server side when we upload file via multipart/form-data. The file name is tönt.png This happens only in Mac(any browser) not in other machines. The same file works in similar applications. The only difference is that content language header is "sv" in the former and 'en-US' in the later.

We did lot of googling, but no luck. We wonder why its not working particular OS

**UPDATE:** Found the cause. It seems Mac treats ö differently than windows. We see below exception in DB

`Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`

Comment: can you show me what you have done so far, or some part of code..

Comment: I have simple Form html which has file upload control. The form is submitted in normal POST action and form is set as multipart/form-data

Comment: it may be the issue of unicode characterset, please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename

Comment: Also check the browser issue mentioned here http://blog.uploadcare.com/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Mac treats ö differently than windows. We see below error in DB logs

`Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`