# Uploaded file question mark icons then turn into chinese characters

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to upload an exported Outlook email into my WordPress website through a plugin. Here's the start of the file in question:
http://prntscr.com/jxil42

When I echo the file this is the result I get.
http://prntscr.com/jximu4
Firstly I don't get where the "?" icons come from, then, when I move the uploaded file and open it, this is the result:
http://prntscr.com/jxinh9

I've no idea what's causing this, any help..?

Answer (score 0):

it may cause of encoding hash, encoding version type as i think

Comment: Can you expand?

Comment: $filename = iconv("utf-8", "cp936", $filename);

Answer (score 0):

Below one will help you to upload the unicode file.

```
$filename = iconv("utf-8", "cp936", $filename);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename)