# How to save utf-8(ñ) in file_put_contents?

Tags: php, utf-8, webcam.js

This code is working. it saves the photo using webcam.js. the problem is when I'm saving file with the file name of Peña its not working. I got a result of PeÃ±a.jpg or Pe?a.jpg file name. but in the database I got it right(peña).

The problem is on the  file_put_contents and rename function.

```
 $photoname = $_POST['photoname'];
    $date1 = date('Ymd');
    $photo_file = 'photos/'.$date.'/'.$date."".$photoname.".jpg";
    $encoded_data = $_POST['mydata'];
    $binary_data = base64_decode( $encoded_data );

    if (!is_dir('photos/' . $month)) {
      // dir doesn't exist, make it
      mkdir('photos/' . $month);
    }

    /*get the image */
    $result = file_put_contents($photo_file, $binary_data);
```

rename function (its also working without special characters).

```
$fname = utf8_decode($_POST['fname']);
$mname = utf8_decode($_POST['mname']);
$lname = utf8_decode($_POST['lname']);

$photo_old = $_POST['photopath'];
$photoname = utf8_decode(strtolower($fname. ''. $mname.''.$lname));
$date1 = date('Ymd');
$month = date('Ymd');
$photo_final = 'photos/'.$month.'/'.$date1."".$photoname.".jpg";
rename($photo_old, $photo_final);
```

result:

```
Warning: rename(photos/20150929/20150929PeÃ±a.jpg,photos/20150930/20150930Pe?a.jpg)
```

Comment: What OS / filesystem? Are you sure it supports UTF-8 filenames?

Comment: windows 8. it saves without having special characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482342/php-readdir-problem-with-japanese-language-file-name/599560#599560

Comment: Long story short: it's better not to try, and use ASCII-only filenames. You can save the Unicode filename in a database as metadata or such.