# PHP error with character 表 (JP)

Tags: php, encode

```
<?php
$str='表/test.zip';
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str,"SJIS−win","UTF−8");
readfile(str);
?>
```

I got error with character 表. Error message is:

```
Warning: readfile(•\/test.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in check.php on line 22 •\/test.zip
```

Of course 表/test.zip had already existed. I tried with other character except for text 表, all were OK, did NOT have any error.

Does anyone have any solution?
Thank you very much for your help.

Note: It is not error about name of file, but error about name of path, name of folder is in JP.
It is difference with [php readdir problem with japanese language file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482342/php-readdir-problem-with-japanese-language-file-name)

Comment: What is the file encoding of the php script? It needs to be UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: That character shows up in a list of "bad" SJIS characters: https://sites.google.com/site/fudist/Home/grep/sjis-damemoji-jp  I suppose it cannot be properly converted.

Comment: If the file is stored in UTF-8, then you shouldn't need to convert `str`.

Comment: is the `$str` variable coming from an SJIS source in the original code? If not, why are you converting the string from SJIS to UTF-8?

Comment: `str` should be `$str`. And `′表/test.zip′` should be `'表/test.zip'`. Can you see the difference? paste it to your text editor.

Comment: @Jeemusu `str` not `$str`. I wonder if str without `$` is possible in lower version of php.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez Not that I can recall, I just assumed OP had mis-typed it when adding the code to the question.

Comment: Using a relative path may be the problem. Try to access the file from an absolute path (eg `/home/me/表/test.zip`). If you cannot get it to work, do a link of the `表` dir to something *romaji*, something like `ln -s 表 uwabe`. Then in php access `uwabe/test.zip`.

Comment: @Thilo: Your comment is the best, you saved my time. Thank you very much. Because it is in this black list. Thank you

Comment: @TinDoan Blacklisted or not, it's binary in a given encoding. So if your OS and file system can access it, the "blacklisting" may not be the problem. When accessing a letter in a given encoding, the system will not check if that gives a particular "blacklisted" character... See my other comment above.