# Why file_get_contents not working in PHP?

Tags: php

This code get content file txt:

```
$str = "c:\\\\表\\t.txt";
$con=file_get_contents( $str);
echo $con;
```

File exist in folder:

[image]

Result: show error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(c:\表\t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 6

Why is `file_get_contents()` not working?

How read content of path c:\表\t.txt?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008341/list-directories-containing-unicode-characters-on-windows

Comment: That character is a bit problematic, there are issues converting it between Unicode and SJIS, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894581/php-error-with-character-%E8%A1%A8-jp#comment57526221_34894581

Comment: Use  `var_dump(is_file("c:\\\\表\\t.txt"), is_readable("c:\\\\表\\t.txt")); ` to debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode your directory name:

```
$str = 'c:\\'.urlencode('表').'\t.txt';
$con=file_get_contents( $str);
echo $con;
```

This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621047/11354) in detail.

**EDIT**

Assuming you're using UTF-8 encoded source files, you could also try one of the following

```
$str = 'c:\\'.urlencode(mb_convert_encoding('表', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8')).'\t.txt';
// or just
$str = 'c:\\'.mb_convert_encoding('表', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8').'\t.txt';
```

As far as I know newer (> FAT32) Microsoft filesystems use UTF-16 encoding. But this will make your solution fail on other (e.g. Linux) filesystems.

**EDIT 2**

You can also try to convert your UTF-8 filename into a different encoding such as `SJIS`, `SJIS-win`, `SJIS-2004`, `JIS`, `EUC-JP`, `eucJP-win`, `EUC-JP-2004`, `CP932`, `JIS-ms`  or the like. But I'm not an expert in east asian character encodings - so treat that information with caution.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(c:\%E8%A1%A8\t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 6

Comment: What's the character encoding of your file? UTF-8?

Comment: my file is utf-8, it still show errror: Warning: : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 6

Comment: i try change UTF-16 to all encode: SJIS, SJIS-win, SJIS-2004, JIS, EUC-JP, eucJP-win, EUC-JP-2004, CP932, JIS-ms, but it still not woking.

Comment: @DT: Then I think you're out of look. If it's an option to change the name of the folder something containing only ASCII characters, the do this and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?PHP
$con=file_get_contents('./表/t.txt', true);
$con=file_get_contents('./表/t.txt',FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

echo $con;
?>
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(C:/表/t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(./表/t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(./表/t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 5

Comment: what is your corrent directory??

Comment: you just try this  `var_dump(getcwd());`

Comment: this my folder "C:\表"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101165/discussion-between-d-t-and-naseeba-c).

Comment: so try this `file_get_contents('./t.txt'.true);`

Answer (score 1):

**Language :** PHP

```
$results = scandir('c:\');
$result will give you all folder name inside c drive.
you can find your folder in $result array.
now you have folder name in $result and now you can go to file.
```

**Modified :**

```
$results = scandir('/web');
$results = "/web/$results[21]/t.txt";
$con=file_get_contents( $results);
echo $con;
```

**Explanation :**

```
1.) /web is the directory where is  表 folder and some other folders.
2.) $result[21] is giving me value è¡¨ on browser i know its 表 folder.
3.) Now you have file path. Go ahead.
```

**NOTE :** If you still use Chinese character in your folder and file then you have to change your OS from window to ubuntu.

Comment: result return folder 表 is  string(2) "�\"

Comment: If you getting folder name in $result[2] then use it in your way.  $str = "C:\$results[2]\.t.txt";
$con=file_get_contents( $str);
echo $con;

Comment: it sill show error : Warning: : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: do one thing. move your file in different drive or make a copy of that file and give permission to that file and apply your approach

Comment: i try move to htdoc, but still can't read file, this problem is folder name =表, if i set folder name ="a", it will read file ok.

Comment: Do you set folder name =表?

Comment: My URL: http://localhost/direction/test.php, C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\表, My code: $results = scandir('/direction'); =>error: Warning: scandir(./direction,./direction): The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Please come in chat. i will explain you there. I have ubuntu OS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101177/discussion-between-monty-and-d-t).

Answer (score 0):

Create path based on single `/`

```
$content = file_get_contents("C:/表/t.txt");
```

You can read more about `Filesystem` here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(c:/表/t.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 3

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(C%3A%2F%E8%A1%A8%2Ft.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\direction\test.php on line 4